# Glossaries - change format of entry names using index (tree) style

Tags: fonts, formatting, glossaries

Does anyone know how to change the format of the entry names in a tree-like style glossary, as the indexhypergroup style?

There, the default seems to be bold, serif font. I'd like to keep the bold, but sans serif, also for the sub-entry and subsubentry names.

As found in the [Glossaries-user Manual](https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf), I've tried it with

`\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textsf{\mdseries #1}}` as well as with

`\renewcommand{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{\textsf{\textbf{\mdseries #1}}}`

however, without success. The sans serif works, but the entries are no longer in bold. What am I doing wrong?

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{myglossary.tex}
\longnewglossaryentry{Nervoussystem}{
name={Nervous system},
text={nervous system},
description={no description needed for parent entry}
}

\longnewglossaryentry{central}{
parent={Nervoussystem},
name={central (CNS)},
text={central nervous system (CNS)},
description={Multi-paragraph explanation of central nervous system, with small indentation between paragraphs. Multi-paragraph explanation of central nervous system.

Multi-paragraph explanation of central nervous system, with small indentation between paragraphs. Multi-paragraph explanation of central nervous system.}
}

\longnewglossaryentry{peripheral}{
parent={Nervoussystem},
name={peripheral (PNS)},
text={peripheral nervous system (PNS)},
description={Multi-paragraph explanation of peripheral nervous system, with small indentation between paragraphs. Multi-paragraph explanation of peripheral nervous system.

Multi-paragraph explanation of peripheral nervous system, with small indentation between paragraphs. Multi-paragraph explanation of peripheral nervous system.}
}

\longnewglossaryentry{gls:Muscle}{
name={Muscle},
description={Description of a Muscle}
}
 
\newacronym{N}{N.}{Nervus}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< acronyms added
\newacronym[see={[see Glossary:]{gls:Muscle}}]{M}{M.}{Musculus\glsadd{gls:Muscle}}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=cyan,linkcolor=black}
\usepackage[toc,acronym,xindy,nopostdot]{glossaries} %edited by Daniela:style=deleted,title= deleted

% to increase space btw glossary entry using index style:
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{\medskip}

% indent adjustments
\renewcommand{\glstreeitem}{% for parent entry
\parindent0pt\par\hangindent20pt
\everypar{\parindent50pt\hangindent20pt}}

\renewcommand{\glstreesubitem}{% for child entry
\parindent30pt\par\hangindent50pt
\everypar{\parindent50pt\hangindent40pt}}

\renewcommand{\glstreesubsubitem}{% for child entry
\parindent50pt\par\hangindent70pt
\everypar{\parindent50pt\hangindent40pt}}

\renewcommand{\glstreepredesc}{\par\glstreeitem\parindent\hangindent}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{myglossary}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex% added
\setacronymstyle{long-short}

\begin{document}

I'd like the entry names as \gls{gls:Muscle}, \gls{Nervoussystem}, as well as the sub entry names as \gls{central} and \gls{peripheral} to appear in bold, sans serif font. \gls{N} and \gls{M} in the list of acronyms, currently looks fine (acronym is shown in bold and sans serif, and on the same line as the description.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Acronyms},toctitle={Acronyms}]%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added

\printglossary[type=main,style=indexhypergroup,title={Glossary},toctitle={Glossary}]% changed by Daniela

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** After follow-up

With updated MWE add

`\renewcommand*{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{{\sffamily \bfseries #1}}`

before `\begin{document}`

The Acronyms page will not be modified.

[image: d]

This is the complete code.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myglossary.tex}
\longnewglossaryentry{Nervoussystem}{% USE here % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
name={Nervous system},
text={nervous system},
description={no description needed for parent entry}
}

\longnewglossaryentry{central}{%
parent={Nervoussystem},
name={central (CNS)},
text={central nervous system (CNS)},
description={Multi-paragraph explanation of central nervous system, with small indentation between paragraphs. Multi-paragraph explanation of central nervous system.

Multi-paragraph explanation of central nervous system, with small indentation between paragraphs. Multi-paragraph explanation of central nervous system.}
}

\longnewglossaryentry{peripheral}{%
parent={Nervoussystem},
name={peripheral (PNS)},
text={peripheral nervous system (PNS)},
description={Multi-paragraph explanation of peripheral nervous system, with small indentation between paragraphs. Multi-paragraph explanation of peripheral nervous system.

Multi-paragraph explanation of peripheral nervous system, with small indentation between paragraphs. Multi-paragraph explanation of peripheral nervous system.}
}

\longnewglossaryentry{gls:Muscle}{%
name={Muscle},
description={Description of a Muscle}
}
 
\newacronym{N}{N.}{Nervus}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< acronyms added
\newacronym[see={[see Glossary:]{gls:Muscle}}]{M}{M.}{Musculus\glsadd{gls:Muscle}}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=cyan,linkcolor=black}
\usepackage[toc,acronym,xindy,nopostdot]{glossaries} %edited by Daniela:style=deleted,title= deleted

\usepackage{xcolor}

% to increase space btw glossary entry using index style:
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{\medskip}

% indent adjustments
\renewcommand{\glstreeitem}{% for parent entry
\parindent0pt\par\hangindent20pt
\everypar{\parindent50pt\hangindent20pt}}

\renewcommand{\glstreesubitem}{% for child entry
\parindent30pt\par\hangindent50pt
\everypar{\parindent50pt\hangindent40pt}}

\renewcommand{\glstreesubsubitem}{% for child entry
\parindent50pt\par\hangindent70pt
\everypar{\parindent50pt\hangindent40pt}}

\renewcommand{\glstreepredesc}{\par\glstreeitem\parindent\hangindent}

\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{myglossary}

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex% added
\setacronymstyle{long-short}


\renewcommand*{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{{\sffamily \bfseries#1}} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}

I'd like the entry names as \gls{gls:Muscle}, \gls{Nervoussystem}, as well as the sub entry names as \gls{central} and \gls{peripheral} to appear in bold, sans serif font. \gls{N} and \gls{M} in the list of acronyms, currently looks fine (acronym is shown in bold and sans serif, and on the same line as the description.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Acronyms},toctitle={Acronyms}]%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< added

\printglossary[type=main,style=indexhypergroup,title={Glossary},toctitle={Glossary}]% changed by Daniela

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @Simon Dispa, many thanks for your help, I really appreciate! Unfortunately, it didn't work in my document. Your solution changed the way my `\acronymtype glossary` looks like, but not my `main glossary` I'm sorry, you couln't know. In fact, I work with an external file `myglossary` where I store both the main glossary entries and the acronym entries. I didn't mention it in the first place, as I didn't know how to make the MWE work with the external file. Is your solution anyhow doable for my main glossary, without changing the acronym glossary? I tried to change the MWE accordingly.

Comment: @Please add a sample of some acronym entries from  your external file and check that your MWE gives the right answer for you, **except for the font issue**.

Comment: Thanks @Simon Dispa for this second chance :-) I think I now got my head around this 'external file in MWE-issue' with the `filecontents environment` - which I added in the original MWE.

Comment: @Daniela A step forward but  still no acronyms ... It does not matter if the definitions are in an external file or in the main document. You need to put a code that prints the acronyms list and the glossaries list the way you like. Then we can start looking to the font issue.

Comment: Yes @Simon Dispa thanks, though I think I've done so. I've added it in my original MWE. There are now 2 acronyms defined `\newacronym{N}{N.}{Nervus},
\newacronym[see={[see Glossary:]{gls:Muscle}}]{M}{M.}{Musculus\glsadd{gls:Muscle}}` plus the `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={Acronyms},toctitle={Acronyms}]` command a bit further down.

Comment: @Daniela Please see the updated answer.

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much @Simon Dispa. I'm very glad and am looking forward to write the next glossary entry. I wish you a great weekend!